# Checking the starting character should be 'T' and next 3 character should be number in xslt

Tags: xslt, tridion

I am using XSLT1.0 for transforming my XML.

I am having below Tabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:ListItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:481-87289-4" Managed="68">
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-596728-64" Title="T000. Brisbane" pageURL="/australia/brisbane/index.aspx" componentTitle="Overview"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-598671-64" Title="Tabs XML"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-598672-64" Title="T030 Special Offers" pageURL="/australia/brisbane/specialoffers.aspx" componentTitle="Special Offers"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-598673-64" Title="020 Flight Schedules" pageURL="/australia/brisbane/flightschedules.aspx" componentTitle="Flight Schedules"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-598674-64" Title="T010 Guide" pageURL="/australia/brisbane/guide.aspx" componentTitle="Guide"/>
</tcm:ListItems>
```

And I am using below xslt to transform it!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:em="http://www.emirates.com/tridion/schemas" xmlns:tcmse="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/TcmScriptAssistant" exclude-result-prefixes="em xlink tcmse tcm">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="tcm:ListItems">
    <list type="Tabs">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tcm:Item">
        <xsl:sort select="@Title" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </list>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- add field values for each item-->
  <xsl:template match="tcm:Item">
    <xsl:if test="@componentTitle != ''">
      <xsl:element name="tab">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@ID, '-')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="title">
          <xsl:value-of select="@componentTitle"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="url">
          <xsl:value-of select="@pageURL"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Previously, it was working fine, but now there is another change required, now I need those node to be rendered whose @Title starts with 'T' or 't' as well as next 3 character should be number for example in above xml "Flight Schedule" shouldn't come, I assume i just need to write one more and condition in `<xsl:if test="@componentTitle != ''">`,

Please suggest! how it can be done!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a simplified one-liner expression and for the standard way to check if a string contains a number. :)

Comment: Good question (+1). And see my better one-liner.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with below solution, please suggest if it is OK!

```
<xsl:template match="tcm:Item">
    <xsl:if test="@componentTitle != '' and (starts-with(translate(@Title, 't', 'T'), 'T')and string(number(substring(@Title,2,3))) != 'NaN')">
      <xsl:element name="tab">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@ID, '-')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="title">
          <xsl:value-of select="@componentTitle"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="url">
          <xsl:value-of select="@pageURL"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Your all input is required!

Comment: Instead of putting your test in the template, you should use it when selecting the nodes, in an `apply-template` element.

Comment: @Oded: The best XSLT style is `pure push`. Don't select, just match. See my solution, and many other answers I've given, for examples of a pure push style.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest expression that will do the matching:

```
translate(substring(@Title, 1, 4), 't12345679', 'T000000000') = 'T000'
```

Here is the template:

```
<xsl:template match="
 tcm:Item[translate(substring(@Title, 1, 4), 't12345679', 'T000000000') = 'T000'
 and @componentTitle != '' "/>
```

Comment: +1 because this is a generally useful pattern. i.e. using translate to make a string match that implements your business rule. And terse without being unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You should *select* the nodes you want to operate on in your templates in the `apply-templates` element:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="tcm:Item[@componentTitle != '' 
                           and (starts-with(translate(@Title, 't', 'T'), 'T') 
                           and string(number(substring(@Title,2,3))) != 'NaN')]">
```

I have used the test that @solution produced for this - it works well for  the requirement (tested [here](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm)).

This is better than selecting all `tcm:Item` nodes and testing them one at a time in the template.

Comment: Even better is the pure "push" style -- don't select, just match.

Answer (score 1):

**The selection logic is best put into the match pattern** of the template -- and it can be a little simplified, too.

```
<xsl:template match=
 "tcm:Item[contains('tT', substring(@Title,1,1))
         and
           number(substring(@Title,2,3)) 
          =    
           number(substring(@Title,2,3)) 
          ]
 ">
```

**One rule to remember**:  Always test if some string `$s` represents a number -- like this:

`number($s) = number($s)`

Answer (score 0):

Working with XSLT only very occasionally, I came up with the following solution:

```
<xsl:if test="@componentTitle != ''">
  <xsl:if test="starts-with(@Title,'T') or starts-with(@Title,'t')"> 
    <xsl:if test="string-length(@Title) &gt; 3">
      <xsl:if test="string(number(substring(@Title,2,3))) != 'NaN'"> 
...
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

I noticed that there are also functions `lower-case`/`upper-case` which could be used for testing for the first character being a `t` or `T` but they seem to be only available in XSLT2.0 .

Comment: Many Thanks Andre for your time and solution, however can you please check below solution proposed my myself!